# Excel VBA Delete selected value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column which has multiple values starting at A2. What I am trying to do is delete a value which is collected from a user form combobox and then remove the blank cell (shift up).
This is what I have Tried So Far:

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Found As Range

RowCount = Worksheets("Config").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Set Found = Worksheets("Config").Columns("B").Find(what:=Me.ProjectManagersCombo.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Found.Delete (xlShiftUp)
```

However this does not work, I get run-time error 91. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like 'Found' is not being 'Set' as the 'Find' method isn't returning any results, so the 'Found.Delete' method can't be called

Comment: ok but the value from the combo box definately has a value from the list in it

Comment: @Socii Ive used this method before (not for deleting though, only comparison) and it works, the delete method is the bit im struggling with

Comment: The `Delete` method works fine in your code, so that doesn't need changing. Try checking to see if `Found` is `Set` before the `Found.Delete` line. `If Found Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Not Set"`

Comment: Found the problem, derp. The data is in column A, i was looking in column B. hence found was not set as the data was in the other column. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

For a = 2 To 1000000
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & a) = _
    Sheet1.Shapes("1").ControlFormat.List(Sheet1.Shapes("1").ControlFormat.ListIndex) _
    Then
        Sheet1.Rows(a).Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next a

End Sub
```

The above sub is assigned to your combobox, Shapes("1") is the combobox shape, change "1" to the name of the shape.

The shorter the better:

```
For a = 2 To 1048576
        If Sheet1.Range("A" & a) = Sheet1.Shapes("1").ControlFormat.List(Sheet1.Shapes("1").ControlFormat.ListIndex) Then Sheet1.Rows(a).Delete: Exit For
Next a
```

Comment: Im sure this probably works, but its alot of work to delete the value. The method above in my original post works I just had a typo and got the wrong column. My method is alot shorter than the for loop as it will only take whats there and not have a maximum limit

Comment: :) any method (find, search, etc.) has to loop to find the search object.

Comment: that be true, however its the number of lines you need in code, the smaller amount of lines the better :)

Comment: Ok :) but I actually have 3 lines of code and you have 5 - the IF part is actually a single line

Comment: `Find` is faster than loop: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment. I learnt something new. I made my own calculations and Find is about 8 times faster than loop.